# remove element from the list then display list without element that remove

Tags: python-3.x, list, nested

I have this nested list:

```
a = [[1, 3, 6, 11, 16, 21, 25, 28, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36], 
     [1, 2, 5, 9, 15, 20, 24, 26, 30, 36], 
     [1, 3, 6, 11, 16, 21, 25, 29, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36], 
     [1, 2, 4, 8, 14, 18, 23, 36], 
     [1, 2, 5, 9, 15, 20, 24, 27, 30, 36], 
     [1, 3, 6, 11, 16, 22, 25, 28, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36], 
     [1, 3, 7, 12, 17, 36], 
     [1, 2, 4, 8, 14, 19, 23, 36], 
     [1, 2, 5, 10, 15, 20, 24, 26, 30, 36], 
     [1, 3, 6, 11, 16, 22, 25, 29, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36], 
     [1, 2, 5, 10, 15, 20, 24, 27, 30, 36], 
     [1, 3, 6, 11, 16, 21, 25, 28, 31, 32, 33, 35, 36], 
     [1, 3, 6, 11, 16, 21, 25, 28, 31, 33, 34, 35,36], 
     [1, 3, 6, 11, 16, 21, 25, 29, 31, 32, 33, 35, 36]]
```

I need to choose max length of sublist in nested list, than compare item of sublist with nested list. If item in sublist equal then same item in nested list remove and in final print nested list without this item.

Comment: did you try anything so far? can you tell what isn't working?

Comment: explain more about your question. Make your question clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understand your question correctly.

You want input to be:

```
a = [[1, 3, 6, 11, 16, 21, 25, 28, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36], 
     [1, 2, 5, 9, 15, 20, 24, 26, 30, 36], 
     [1, 3, 6, 11, 16, 21, 25, 29, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36], 
     [1, 2, 4, 8, 14, 18, 23, 36], 
     [1, 2, 5, 9, 15, 20, 24, 27, 30, 36], 
     [1, 3, 6, 11, 16, 22, 25, 28, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36], 
     [1, 3, 7, 12, 17, 36], 
     [1, 2, 4, 8, 14, 19, 23, 36], 
     [1, 2, 5, 10, 15, 20, 24, 26, 30, 36], 
     [1, 3, 6, 11, 16, 22, 25, 29, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36], 
     [1, 2, 5, 10, 15, 20, 24, 27, 30, 36], 
     [1, 3, 6, 11, 16, 21, 25, 28, 31, 32, 33, 35, 36], 
     [1, 3, 6, 11, 16, 21, 25, 28, 31, 33, 34, 35, 36], 
     [1, 3, 6, 11, 16, 21, 25, 29, 31, 32, 33, 35, 36]]
```

We are removing

```
[1, 3, 6, 11, 16, 22, 25, 29, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36]
```

and

```
[1, 3, 6, 11, 16, 21, 25, 29, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36]
```

since they are of the same length.

The output should be:

```
a = [[1, 2, 5, 9, 15, 20, 24, 26, 30, 36], 
     [1, 2, 4, 8, 14, 18, 23, 36], 
     [1, 2, 5, 9, 15, 20, 24, 27, 30, 36], 
     [1, 3, 7, 12, 17, 36], 
     [1, 2, 4, 8, 14, 19, 23, 36], 
     [1, 2, 5, 10, 15, 20, 24, 26, 30, 36], 
     [1, 2, 5, 10, 15, 20, 24, 27, 30, 36], 
     [1, 3, 6, 11, 16, 21, 25, 28, 31, 32, 33, 35, 36], 
     [1, 3, 6, 11, 16, 21, 25, 28, 31, 33, 34, 35, 36], 
     [1, 3, 6, 11, 16, 21, 25, 29, 31, 32, 33, 35, 36]]
```

with the previous lists removed.

Your question was not worded clearly, but I hope this is what you wanted. Here is the code:

```
# assume a is not empty
d = {} # list of the max length -> number of occurrences in 2d array

# find the length of the longest list
maxLen = len(a[0])
for l in a:
    if len(l) > maxLen:
        maxLen = len(l)

# add lists of the same max length and their count to the dictionary
for l in a:
    if len(l) == maxLen:
        #convert list to string because python does not support list being key of a dictionary
        l_string = str(l)
        if l_string in d:
            d[l_string] += 1
        else:
            d[l_string] = 1

# remove
for l_string in d:
    while d[l_string] > 0:
        # convert string back to list and remove
        a.remove(eval(l_string))
        d[l_string] -= 1

# test result if you want
for row in a:
    print(row)
```